# How to (de)serialize game-changing cards behavior in a board game?

Tags: java, oop, serialization, game-development

I'm working on a board game. During each turn, the player can use a card (paying some tokens) that will, for example, allow them to draw another card, allow them to place his pawn on the board ignoring some rule (only for a turn), allow them to re-roll a die and so on. I've been asked to load these cards from a JSON file so that one can add new cards to the game without recompiling/updating the entire software, and also because "hardcoding them would be bad".

1. the cards have a name and a cost, and this is quite simple to serialize. But when it comes to serialize their behavior and their effects i'm lost. I thought i could think of each atomic effect these cards provide, store the appropriate ones in a JSON array of strings (for each card) and then have a huge switch case in the method `useCard()` that will cycle over the array of effects. But i feel this would be a hack since i would still be hardcoding the effects in the software, just in a more intricate way. If i were to add a new card with a completely new behavior (e.g. throw your computer out of the window) i'd have to update and redistribute the software. When I confronted my supervisor about this, he said "Well, you're right, but at least you could write some debug cards and test all of the effects at once". I'm still not convinced. What is a better way to (de)serialize the behavior of a card?
2. all of these cards should be a Java instance of the same class, let's call it ActionCard. Suppose this class offers a method `useCard()`. However, some cards can be used only if certain conditions are met, or their effect needs a parameter (e.g. if the card lets you re-roll a die, what die would you like to re-roll?). How can i put all of this complex behavior under the `useCard()` big umbrella? I thought of using varargs and then the switch case would take care of the parameters; i also thought of overloading the `useCard()` method having a ton of versions of it, but it still smells of a hack.

I know it sounds really vague, but i cannot give many details about the game itself; if you need more informations let me know and i will update/comment the question. But i think this same question could apply to other games, the first crossing my mind being Clash Royale and Magic the Gathering Online.
Also, i don't need working code, just some ideas and tips from other minds. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm using gson as the serializing library. I already wrote some `TypeAdapter`s so i can make it work with complex data types.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create your own "programming language". You store the effect of the cards as a string. You can then write some code that parses and interprets the string and alters the game state according to the string. Some examples would be:

```
dealer draws 3 if hand < 5
dealer rerollDice 1
opponent loses 3
dealer ignoresRule 3 1
```

They mean:

```
dealer can draw 3 cards if he has less than 5 cards
dealer re-rolls the first dice
opponent loses 3 of his cards randomly
dealer can ignore rule number 3 (whatever that maybe) for one turn
```

I have come up with this rather simple system here. The first word is who the effect affects, the second word is the command and everything after that but before the word `if` is the parameters for the command.

Obviously this is just an example. You probably want to design the language so that it can be used to control all aspects of the game. A good place to start is to look at your `Player` class (you probably have one right?). What methods do your `Player` class have? That is probably a good place to start.

Create classes for the "commands" like `draws` and `rerollDice` and they should probably implement a common interface like `Command`:

```
interface Command {
    void execute(String[] args, GameState state) {
        // mutate game state here
    }
}
```

Your "language" can also allow multiple statements that are executed procedurally. So instead of creating a new command called `drawsAndLoses`:

```
dealer drawsAndLoses 3 1
// dealer can draw 3 cards but then loses one card randomly
```

you can just do the same thing with two "statements":

```
dealer draws 3
dealer loses 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable conception would be that your class ActionCard contains a list of Effect, where Effect would be an interface with a method perform().
You will, of course, have to write down all possibe effects with what parameters they take and develop that many implementations of Effect.

The consequence of that is that your serialization has to be polymorphic.

To know what kind of object you are going to deserialize, at serialization time, also write an object tag.
In its simplest form, it could be the fully qualified name of the Effect implementation.

Here's a simple example. Imagine that you are going to read a list of items, where each item can be a String, an Integer or a Date.
Your list could be serialized as:

```
[
  {"type": "java.lang.String", "value": "Hello"},
  {"type": "java.lang.String", "value": "World"}
  {"type": "java.lang.Integer", "value": 123}
  {"type": "java.lang.String", "value": "Hi!"},
  {"type": "java.util.Date", "value": {"year": 2018, "month": 5, "day": 12}},
  {"type": "java.lang.Integer", "value": 456}
]
```

The type field is our identifying tag. Depending on what it contains, you know what kind of object you are going to find in the value field.
OF course it's much safer to use a string, a number or an enum as tag, especially if players can modifiy serialized data; but now at least you have the basic idea.